# SAP web service reference in .NET naming conflict issue

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sap-dotnet-connector

i have a .net issue  when im  trying to consume SAP ws ,
the element system cusing this error

```
  error CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Bapiret2.System'
```

their is a solution   as described  here BUT im want to find a solution that doesn't required to change the WSDL

http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2009/04/17/system-namespace-conflict-in-sap-web-services.aspx

or this one ,
http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2009/09/sap-to-microsoft-net-integration-fixes.html

do you have any experience with that and how you solve it?

thanks 
miki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because System namespace in both Windows and BAPI. This can be dealt with by adding global:: before all calls giving the above errors. This does not involve editing WSDL.

References: Comment on one of the [page](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2009/04/17/system-namespace-conflict-in-sap-web-services.aspx) you mentioned above and [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that comment referred to.

Answer (score 8):

Since this issue is caused by naming conflict in .NET and SAP, another workaround for this issue without changing SAP configuration：

Add an alias for System.XML as below in Reference.cs

```
using SysXml = System.Xml;
```

Then, replace all the System.Xml where report the error with "SysXml" as below (please note that the word "SysXml" is originally "System.Xml" after adding the service, which caused this issue)

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=SysXml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string Type {
    get {
        return this.typeField;

    set {
        this.typeField = value;
    }
}
```